# Explosive Cox process

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, extreme-value-theorem

Let $X_0,\dots,X_n,\dots$ be a sequence of independent variables and let each $X_k$ be distributed according to an exponential distribution of parameter $\lambda a^{-k}$  (with $a<1$):

$$X_k \sim \text{Exponential}(\lambda a^{-k}) \Leftrightarrow \mathbb{P}(X_k<x) = 1- \exp(\lambda a^{-k} x)$$

Now define:

$$Y = \sum_{k=0}^\infty X_k $$

It is straightforward to show that the variable $Y$ has finite expectation and finite variance:

$$ \mu_Y = \mathbb{E}(Y) = \frac{1}{\lambda}\frac{1}{1-a}, \qquad \sigma_Y^2 = \mathbb{E}(Y^2)-\mathbb{E}^2(Y)  < \infty$$

Moreover, for small values of n it is possible to calculate in a simple way the distribution of $Y_N$

$$Y_N = \sum_{k=0}^N X_k$$

using the characteristic function formalism. But for N tending to infinity, it does not seem to express the distribution of $Y$ as closed form. I have simulated that $Y$ is distributed as follows a [Fréchet distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_distribution), which makes sense since it is an extreme value distribution, which appears in the [Fisher–Tippett–Gnedenko theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Tippett%E2%80%93Gnedenko_theorem). Note that $\tilde{N}_t = \#\{i \ge 1: Y_N \le t \}$ is an **explosive Cox Process**.

How could it be formally demonstrated que $Y \sim \text{Fréchet}(\cdot,\cdot)$ ?

---

*Additional comment*: The characteristic function of $Y_N$ is given by:

$$\phi_{Y_n} = \mathbb{E}(e^{it(X_1+\dots+X_n}) = \prod_{i=k}^N \left(1-\frac{it}{\lambda a^{-k}}\right)^{-1}$$

for low $N$ is relatively easy to compute the Fourier transform of this function to obtain the probability density function of $Y_N$.

Comment: There's something off here: If $X_k$ has parameter $\lambda a^k$ then $\Bbb E[X_k]=\lambda^{-1} a^{-k}$, which is inconsistent with your formula for $\Bbb E[Y]$.

Comment: @JohnDawkins There was an errorm the parameter of $X_k$ is indeed $\lambda a^{-k}$ (with $a <1$). Thank you very much for your observation.

Comment: Can you say more about the characteristic functions? You alluded to having calculated them... what did you obtain?

Comment: @AaronMontgomery additional comments about characteristic function have been added.